# urlManager in yii

Tags: php, url, yii

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
               'ongSpcl/<category:.*?>'=>'ongSpcl/index',
            ),
        ),
```

The above code reads the url "abc.co/ongSpcl/sp1" as "abc.co/ongSpcl?category=sp1
It works!
But my issue is I want to read all the url in the above format except for "abc.co/ongSpcl/**index**"

Answer (score 0):

Put a rule for `'ongSpcl/index'=>ongSpcl/index` (change the right side to whatever route you want) prior to your existing rule. Yii will execute the first match it finds.

Also, fyi, you can use `<category:\w+>` to *match any non-null strings of alphanumeric characters* if that's your intention.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bt the answer is not solving my purpose. The code I provided is doing gr8(it reads abc.co/ongSpcl/category1 as abc.co/ongSpcl?category=category1) bt I want to add an exception for "index" so dat abc.co/ongSpcl/index will b read as abc.co/ongSpcl/index

Comment: I still refer you to my answer. Perhaps it would help if you posted your full urlManager code.

Answer (score 0):

Removing trailing `index` from Yii Url, change show category action from `ongSpcl#index` to something else, then add `'/ongSpcl' => 'ongSpcl/index'`,

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'rules'=>array(
    '/ongSpcl' => 'ongSpcl/index',
    '/ongSpcl/<category:.*?>'=>'ongSpcl/show',
  ),
),
```

Stub for testing routes

```
class RoutingTest extends CTestCase {
  public function createUrl($route, $params=array()) {
    $url = explode('phpunit', Yii::app()->createUrl($route, $params));
    return $url[1];
  }

  public function testCorrectRoutes() {
    $this->assertEquals('/ongSpcl', $this->createUrl('ongSpcl/index'));
    $this->assertEquals('/ongSpcl/sp1', $this->createUrl('ongSpcl/show', array('category' => 'sp1'));
    //
  }
```